# VBA to save CSV file to Excel with specific column formats

Tags: vba, excel

I'm fairly sure this is a simple request but I don't generally use any VBA scripts so it's beyond my knowledge.

I have a folder of about 700 .csv files that are "|" delimited, essentially all I want to do is open this particular folder and convert all the .csv files to .xls AND make all columns formatted as "text" rather than "general." I did some searching and found the exact code to convert the files however I can't figure out how to also make the columns text. Any help would be greatly appreciated! I've tried looking but if the answer is else where please point me in the right direction. (Below is the code that works for the .csv to .xls)

```
Sub CSVtoXls()
Dim CSVfolder As String
Dim XlsFolder As String
Dim fname As String
Dim wBook As Workbook 
CSVfolder = "C:\Users\del44\Desktop\CSV Files\"
XlsFolder = "C:\Users\del44\Desktop\Excel Files\" 
fname = Dir(CSVfolder & "*.csv") 
Do While fname <> ""
Set wBook = Workbooks.Open(CSVfolder & fname, Format:=6, Delimiter:="|")
wBook.SaveAs XlsFolder & Replace(fname, ".csv", ".xls")
wBook.Close False
fname = Dir
Loop
Dim rCell As Range
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewritten. Test to see if this now works.

```
Sub CSVtoXls()

Dim CSVfolder As String
Dim XlsFolder As String
Dim fname As String
Dim LnLastRow As Long
Dim StString As String
Dim StSplit() As String
Dim wBook As Workbook
CSVfolder = "C:\Users\del44\Desktop\CSV Files\"
XlsFolder = "C:\Users\del44\Desktop\Excel Files\" 
fname = Dir(CSVfolder & "*.csv")
Do While fname <> ""
Set wBook = Workbooks.Open(CSVfolder & fname, Format:=6, Delimiter:="|")
LnLastRow = wBook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
For i = 1 To LnLastRow
    StString = wBook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1)
    StSplit() = Split(Mid(StString, 1), "|")
    For j = LBound(StSplit) To UBound(StSplit)
        wBook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, (j + 1)) = "'" & StSplit(j)
    Next j
Next i
wBook.SaveAs XlsFolder & Replace(fname, ".csv", ".xls"), FileFormat:=56
wBook.Close False
fname = Dir
Loop

Dim rCell As Range

End Sub
```

I've quit the option to ".textocolumns" and instead I'm splitting each cell. See if this helps!

Comment: Thanks for responding but the code is giving me the same results as my original. More specifically my problem is excel is dropping my leading zeros, perhaps you can test with columns that have numbers with leading zeros?

Comment: I've rewritten my previous code, to now split each cell.

Comment: Thanks again for all your help... I ran into a similar issue with .txt files. I thought simply changing the VB script from .CSV to .TXT would solve the problem but it does not, any reason why this code would not work for .txt files? And by "not working" I mean is drops the leading zeros.

Answer (score 1):

CSV conversion can be a pain in the butt!

However, I've tested your situation with a simple CSV file that looks this

```
Scott|00001234|test
Mark|10101010|test
Brian|01010201|test
```

And the following code worked for me. *(I book-ended the lines from your original code on where to insert the code to format the cells.)*

```
Set wBook = Workbooks.Open(CSVfolder & fname, Format:=6, Delimiter:="|")

wBook.Sheets(1).Columns(1).TextToColumns _
        Destination:=Range("A1"), _
        DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
        ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
        Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, _
        Comma:=False, _
        Space:=False, _
        Other:=True, _
        OtherChar:="|", _
        '*** this is the key! ****
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 2), Array(3, 1)), _
        TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

wBook.SaveAs XlsFolder & Replace(fname, ".csv", ".xls")
```

The key to this working is the `FieldInfo` argument. I'll explain what it's doing, because it's going to require you to adjust it to suit your data.

- The `Array` holds elements equal to the number of delimited columns in the file (in my case there were three).
- Each element is an `Array` itself
- `Array(1,1)` means that the first column in formatted as `General`
- `Array(2,2)` means that the 2nd column is formatted as `Text`
- for good measure `Array(3,1)` means the 3rd column is formatted as `General`

For more understanding, see Step 3 in the `Convert Text to Columns Wizard` when converting text-to-columns manually.

Comment: Appreciate your feedback, but the resulting files seems to be the same as my original. I specifically need the resulting columns to be text because on the conversion excel drops the leading zeros. Perhaps you can try testing with columns that have numbers with leading zeros?

Comment: @Scotty_ , when the workbook opens (the csv) workbook into excel does it have the leading zeros? If so, then move the `With` block in my code between the Open and Save methods.

Comment: Yes, when I open the csv file and excel open the leading zeros are there. I tried moving the "with" block but it appears to be the same outcome (file is converted w/o the leading zero). Perhaps I'm doing something wrong, can you edit/re-post your code?

Comment: ^*typo-when I open the csv file in excel it open with the leading zeros*